# `react-hook-form` display error message on empty input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

**Expected behaviour:**
When the form submit button is hit before anything is in the text input, the error message is displayed.

**Current behaviour:**
The error message is only displayed once in input has a value, even after hitting submit. Meaning the user has to click on and type in the textfield before the error message will appear.

[Minimal codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-error-not-showing-until-input-has-value-gl4v2)

I know it was possible to do this in earlier versions of [`react-hook-form`](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Handleerrors), I think it was the default behaviour actually, surely theres still a way? It seems so simple.

```
<form className="App" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
      <TextField
        label="Attribution"
        variant="outlined"
        helperText={
          Boolean(errors.attribution)
            ? errors.attribution.message
            : "Who is being quoted?"
        }
        {...register("attribution", {
          required: true,
          minLength: { value: 3, message: "Please enter a longer name" },
          maxLength: { value: 50, message: "Please enter a shorter name" }
        })}
        error={Boolean(errors.attribution)}
      />
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I realised it can be fixed *easily* by changing

```
{...register("attribution", {
          required: true,
          minLength: { value: 3, message: "Please enter a longer name" },
          maxLength: { value: 50, message: "Please enter a shorter name" }
        })}
```

to

```
{...register("attribution", {
          required: 'Your name is required', // <- right here
          minLength: { value: 3, message: "Please enter a longer name" },
          maxLength: { value: 50, message: "Please enter a shorter name" }
        })}
```

Very cool.

[Relevant `react-hook-form` docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register).

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a message, otherwise the field will just turn red

```
{...register("attribution", {
   required: { value: true, message: "Field is required" },
   minLength: { value: 3, message: "Please enter a longer name" },
   maxLength: { value: 50, message: "Please enter a shorter name" }
})}
```